# Google Sheets formula that returns all DEC YYYY & results?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

**This is an example.
*Also, I'd greatly appreciate if the results can be (conditional format) a different font color inside the left table.*** **Thank you, blessings (1 Corinthians 15 KJV)!**

[image: Google Sheets formula that returns all DEC YYYY & results? Thank you, blessings (1 Corinthians 15 KJV)!]

Comment: what do you want to achieve ? just change the font of the left table ?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(A:B, "where month(A)+1 = 12", 0)
```